# Simplification of a function

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I have to simplify the following function :

$g(x)$ = ${\sin x\over \sin 1} \cos (x-1)-{\sin x\over \sin 1} \cos 1 + {\sin (x-1)\over \sin 1} \cos 1-{\sin (x-1) \over \sin 1} \cos x.$

My attempt:

$\implies g(x)$=${1\over \sin 1}[ \sin x \cos (x-1)-\sin (x-1) \cos x]+{\cos 1\over \sin 1} [ \sin (x-1) - \sin x]$

$\implies (x)$=$1+ {\cos 1\over \sin 1}[\sin x \cos 1 -\cos x\sin 1-\sin x]$

$\implies g(x)$=$1+ {\cos 1\over \sin 1}[\sin x [\cos 1-1] -\cos x\sin 1]$

$\implies g(x)$=$1-\cos x\cos 1+\cos 1[{\cos 1-1 \over \sin 1} \sin x]$

But the answer is

$g(x)$=$1-\cos x+[{\cos 1-1 \over \sin 1} \sin x].$

What have i done wrong ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the relation $$\cos(A-B) = \cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)$$

Comment: @johny: Please check again if the $g(x)$ you first wrote is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One error is at the end of the first line in your attempt. The group

$${\cos 1\over \sin 1} [ \sin (x-1) + \sin x]$$

should be

$${\cos 1\over \sin 1} [ \sin (x-1) - \sin x]$$

right?

Comment: yes you are correct that was just a typing error i have edited it

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem any mistake in your steps. I think the text book has missed $cos 1$ (provided you wrote your question correct).